# Dump Contents of Directories Into Directory PHP

Tags: php, directory

I have a directory like this :

```
/images/
```

and then I have another directory like this

```
/waiting/pack1/
```

but I have a bunch of packs, so I was wondering how I could make a script to dump all the contents of these `/pack*` directories into the `/images/` one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [directory recursive iterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) to get all the file names. Loop on the result (file names) and move them inside the loop to the desired directory.
You can also try with [glob](http://php.net/glob)